# How to remove some spaces behind a character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to remove double spaces behind a character, like `"text    :something"`, remove all the spaces behind `':'`
I tried this code,  But it did not work:

```
var myStr = 'text    :something';
var myNewStr = myStr.replace(/\s:{1,}/g, ':');
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your regex turns a single space and then 1 or more colons into a single colon.

Comment: Also, `{1,}` is equivalent to the `+` sign, meaning *one or more*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select one or more spaces and then the colon and replace with a colon.

```
/\s+:/g
```

or

```
myStr.replace(/\s+:/g, ':');
```

Answer (score 0):

move the colon.

```
/\s{1,}:/g
```

blah blah blah (need more characters)